# Need Help Parsing a Text File in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have text file file1.txt of the format as shown below

```
1
A:  24
B:  6
C: -33

2
A:  44
B:  5
C:  78

3
A:  32
B: -98
C:  22
```

I need my perl program to parse this text file and output as file2.txt :

```
      1      2      3
 A    24     6     -33      
 B    44     5      78
 C    32    -98     22
```

Thanks for help in advance

Have Tried something but that is not working correctly. But based on other's feedback I have posted the code.

```
# Program to parse output
@split1 = split(/\//,$ENV{'DESIGN_PATH'});

open (FILE1,"<path_to_file1.txt");
open (FILE2,">path_to_file2.txt"); 
my $go = 0;

while ($line = <FILE1>) {
print $line;
# Remove Blank SPaces
chomp $line;
@sp = split(/ /,$line);

$n=0;
for ($i=0; $i<=$#sp; $i++) {
  if ($sp[$i] eq "") {
  } else {
  $arry[$n] = $sp[$i];
  $n++;
  }
}

if ($line =~ /A:/ && $go == 0) {
  $go = 1;
  $group = $arry[$n-1];
  print FILE2 "- -\n";
  print FILE2 "B $arry[$n-1]\n";
}

if ($line =~ /B:/ && $go == 1) {
  $go = 0;
  print FILE2 "B: $arry[$n-1]\n";
} elsif ($line =~ /C:/ && $go == 1) {
  print FILE2 "C: $arry[$n-1]\n";
}


}
close FILE1;
```

Comment: We cannot help you to fix your code unless you show it. Please add the Perl code that isn't working to your question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have posted code snippet that I tried and doesnt work

Comment: @Borodin Since I am newbee to perl did not want to post code that I was trying, but I have updated now

Comment: @Dylan : Can you look into this question ?

Comment: @Borodin : Based on you request I have added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accumulate your data into a HoH or some other data structure, and then output it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my %data;

local $/ = '';    # Paragraph mode
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $column, $vals ) = split "\n", $_, 2;

    while ( $vals =~ m/(.*):\s*(.*)/g ) {
        $data{$column}{$1} = $2;
    }
}

my @columns = sort keys %data;
my @rows = sort +uniq map { keys %$_ } values %data;

print join( "\t", '', @columns ), "\n";
for my $row (@rows) {
    print join( "\t", $row, map { $data{$_}{$row} // '' } @columns ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
1
A:  24
B:  6
C: -33

2
A:  44
B:  5
C:  78

3
A:  32
B: -98
C:  22
```

Outputs:

```
    1   2   3
A   24  44  32
B   6   5   -98
C   -33 78  22
```

Comment: It gives error in this line `use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);`

Comment: What do you mean by HoH ?

Comment: [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) is a basic CPAN module that you can install.  [How to install CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

Comment: HoH is shorthand for a hash of hashes.  That and other concepts are discussed in [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)